# Finding null character using Regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find the null characters in an array, which I have. I tried displaying the ASCII value and it printed 0 (So I am confirmed it is a null value). How do I write a regex to filter out those values.

I wrote :

```
m/^$/ig
```

which really didn't help me. Does anybody know how to match a null character ?

Comment: Is there any method to write ASCII value in regex to match it ?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $yourvariable` will show you exactly what the hidden character is.

Comment: $VAR1 = "";   I got this diaplay @TLP

Comment: That means the variable is empty then, no null character there. It should match `/^$/`. It should also be considered "false" in a boolean check, such as `if ($var)`. You can also check `$var !~ /./s`, meaning it fails a check for any character. It depends on your situation what the best way to check it is.

Comment: I used $var !~ /./s,  and I got the desired output. Thank you very much TLP :)

Comment: Also there are some elements like []  What does these means by Dumper ? @TLP

Comment: If you mean `$VAR = []` that is an empty array. Such that you would get if you did `print Dumper \@array`, where `@array = ()`.

Comment: The `Data::Dumper` module is one of the best debugging tools, right after `use strict; use warnings;`. Learn to use it, and you will have an invaluable tool at your side.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\x` followed by the hex code of an ASCII character to match that ASCII character.

E.g. `/\x3F/` will match a "?", `/\x46\x4F\x4F/` to match "FOO".

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34itl)

So `/\x00/` would match the NULL character.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `\0` to find null character. (but do not follow this with another digit)

Comment: It really didn't help me out :(

Comment: did you try it in regex? like `/\0/ims`

Comment: maybe its not a null char, its an invisible whitespace. try this in that case `/\p{Z}/`

Comment: I tried display using "ord", which displayed as 0. Can we still say it is not a null character ?

Answer (score -2):

0x0 should do the trick.

0x[0-9A-F] to find any hex char

Comment: Well I said it was a ASCII value 0 , not a hex value.

Comment: hex 0x30 == ascii 0. Can you try printing the mystery char out as a hex string?